# AsyncTaskLoader third task disappears

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, asynctaskloader, android-loader

I'm trying to implement a list/detail workflow where a tap on a list item causes the detail section to load data related to the newly selected row.  I'm trying to use an `AsyncTaskLoader` to accomplish this.  I'm running into a problem where if I tap three list items quickly enough in a row, only two of the loads actually occur and the third gets lost.

I've written a sample activity that demonstrates this behavior.  When tapping the button three times, the `loadInBackground()` method is only getting called twice.  Am I missing a call somewhere?

```
public final class LoaderActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Integer> {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loader);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.load_button);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View source) {
        Loader<Integer> loader = getLoaderManager().getLoader(0);
        if (loader != null) {
            loader.forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Integer> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new IntLoader(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Integer> listLoader, Integer data) {
        button.setText(String.valueOf(data));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Integer> listLoader) {

    }

    private static final class IntLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Integer> {

        private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

        IntLoader(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer loadInBackground() {
            int result = counter.getAndIncrement();

            // Simulate a potentially expensive web call
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStopLoading() {
            cancelLoad();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReset() {
            onStopLoading();
        }

        @Override
        public void deliverResult(Integer data) {
            if (isStarted()) {
                super.deliverResult(data);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the method is only getting called twice? Or could it be possible that the message is getting called 3 times but only 2 times is the UI getting updated by the call to `setText`. `onLoadFinished` is not synced with the UI thread by default, so that is why I am wondering.

Comment: Absolutely certain it's the `loadInBackground()` only getting called twice - I've set a breakpoint at the beginning of `loadInBackground()`.

Comment: (OK actually I'm not 100% certain about `onLoadFinished` being called on the main UI thread or not... this seems to be a source of confusion because CommonsWare and Reto Meier both take opposite sides in their books haha... I'll get back to you on that.)

Comment: BTW, shouldn't you make the call to `forceLoad()` in `onStartLoading` instead?

Comment: There's really nothing to load right when the activity starts up.  It's not until a list item is chosen (or in my contrived example the button is tapped) that an actual load needs to occur.  Should I still be calling `forceLoad()` from `onStartLoading()` anyway?

Comment: if you take a look at the `CursorLoader.java` source code, you'll see that it implements `onStartLoading`, forcing the load if the `Cursor` is not `null`. This means the client won't have to worry about force-loading the `CursorLoader` in the `Activity` code himself... it will be called on the `Loader` after `initLoader` and after `onCreateLoader` has returned.

Comment: My thinking is that this isn't really a "bug"... once you have handed control of your `Loader` to the `LoaderManager`, the `LoaderManager` will manage the `Loader` on its own, starting/stopping/resetting the `Loader` with respect to the `Activity` and `Fragment` lifecycles (and not necessarily UI events). This example is a little trivial too... you obviously wouldn't create a `Loader` to increment an atomic integer, right? So long as the `Loader` is able to `forceload()` when underlying changes to its data source are detected, this wouldn't be an issue right?

Comment: So is a `Loader` not really appropriate to use when the data needs to be reloaded in response to UI events then?  I know my example is a bit trivial, but as I said in the question, I am trying to use a `Loader` to update a detail view as different items are chosen in a list.  I don't want anything to be loaded when the `Activity` is initially shown, only once an item is chosen in the list.

Comment: please forgive me for my ignorance. but should't restricting/disabling the listview during loading of data help you?... i mean why dont u just stop the user from clicking/tapping quickly when the data is being loaded.

Comment: @Aamir Disallowing a new item from being chosen in the list would certainly work but it's not the best user experience.  If the user accidentally tapped the wrong row I'd like to let him/her choose the correct row (canceling the previous load), and start the load for the correct row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `restartLoader(0, null, this)` instead of `getLoader(0)` in the `onButtonClick()` method seems to have solved this problem.  As I'm learning more about `Loader`s it sounds like the more appropriate method to call since I'm wanting to discard any old results at that point.